# Change Activity Monitor update speed?

Tags: cpu, activity-monitor, time

When viewing the CPU Load on Activity Monitor today, I was curious as how to make Activity Monitor update the chart and data faster.

Is there a setting to change the update speed for Activity Monitor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the update speed, open Activity Monitor and select View > Update Frequency.

You can choose between three options:

- Very often (1 sec)
- Often (2 sec)
- Normal (5 sec)